# Is it possible in Jinja2 to have this behaviour?

Tags: templates, macros, jinja2

I have a list of strings that I will process and for brevity sake I am writing them as spans here.

I want some html to go inside a div, so,

```
<div class="something">
  <span>something1</span>
  <span>something2</span>
  <span>something3</span>
  ...
</div>
```

And some other outside (depending on some condition)

```
  <span>something-else1</span>
  <span>something-else2</span>
  <span>something-else3</span>
  ...
```

So the condition comes from something in the list. Is there any way so I can stop the control at a macro caller so I can have the same macro be called again so it would append the next span in the same place?

So something like

```
{% macro render_inside_div %}
  <div class="something">
    {{ caller() }} <-- I want to render multiple spans in within the same div
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

EDIT:

Yes, of course that would work and that is (sort of) how I got it to work anyways. But I was looking for a 'cleaner' and DRY solution. So basically I would just iterate the list once and the way it would work would be something like this:

```
{% for row in my_list %}
  {% if row.condition_for_div %}
    {% call render_in_div %}  {# Look before to see the macro I've written above #}
      {{ do_something(row.data) }}
    {% endcall %}
  {% else %}
    {{ do_something(row.data) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

so in this `render_in_div` I want to hand control to the caller() block many times, so the control (for that "context") would remain there until I say to get out (in some way like a generator?)

Comment: Where did you get a data for that `div`? From collection? If so, you may use `{% for item in collection if condition %}` to render some items in a `div`, then same `{% for ... if !condition %}` to render "outside" `spans`.